# React App and Spring Boot serving form different context

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

HI I have set up a basic spring boot app and react fornt end. all packaged inside using the folloowing tutorial

https://blogg.kantega.no/webapp-with-create-react-app-and-spring-boot/

its all working when i run the spring boot app and go to localhost:8080, i see the react logo.

What i would like to do is set up a servlet path like /company, and have my react app work from there.. but that doesnt seem to work. Is there anyway to do this?

```
server.servlet.context-path=/company
```

my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>frontend</workingDirectory>
        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v8.9.4</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a restcontroller and return the html

```
@RestController
public class Foobar {

    @GetMapping("/company")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getHtml(@Value("classpath:/public/index.html") Resource html) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(html).contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
    }
}
```

i havn't tried it, but i remember doing something like this some time ago. Wrote this code from free hand, but you get the point off it.